# Is the approach for ExceptionHandling changed in PostSharp 5.x?

Tags: postsharp

Pre PostSharp 5.x, Exception handling was done by inheriting from OnExceptionAspect().
Is there a new approach in 5.x similar to Audit log done with AuditServices.RecordPublished event handler?

Answer (score 0):

To log exceptions thrown by methods, you can use PostSharp Diagnostics Library - see http://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging.

To log exceptions only (not each method entry to and exit), use the `LogExceptionsAttribute` custom attribute instead of the `LogAttribute` custom attribute. See http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_diagnostics_logexceptionattribute.

To perform other actions when a method trows en exception, there is still the `OnExceptionAspect` aspect. See http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling.

Comment: When intercepting an exception using OnExceptionAspect, I can apply the attribute at class level or method level. How can I apply it at assembly level or solution level?

Comment: Applying aspects is documented at http://doc.postsharp.net/applying-aspects. Applying to the whole assembly is described at http://doc.postsharp.net/attribute-multicasting. Applying aspects to the whole solution can be done by creating a file called <YourSolutionName>.pssln in the folder where the <YourSolutionName>.sln file is located and setting it up as described at http://doc.postsharp.net/xml-multicasting.  PostSharp configuration is described at http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-system.

Comment: http://doc.postsharp.net/xml-multicasting deals with psproj. The examples in http://samples.postsharp.net have no pssln file. Can you provide me any samples with OnExceptionAspect and pssln ?

Comment: The content of the configuration files is the same. The difference is just where PostSharp is looking for them. (As described in http://doc.postsharp.net/configuration-system - "Well-known configuration files".)

Comment: I have ExceptionSwallow.dll in which I have the below code           `namespace ExceptionSwallow
{
    [PSerializable]
    public sealed class SwallowException : OnExceptionAspect
    { }
}`  I have the below contents in PSSLN ` <Multicast xmlns:my="clr-namespace:ExceptionSwallow;assembly:ExceptionSwallow">
    <my:SwallowException  AttributeTargetTypes="ClassLibrary2.Class2" />'  I get the error "error PS0201: Cannot find the type 'ExceptionSwallow.SwallowException, ExceptionSwallow'.

Comment: Please make sure that ExceptionSwallow.dll is referenced in ClassLibrary2 project. If it is, please add this as a new question and provide a full solution so we can have a better look.

Comment: Referencing ExceptionSwallow.dll in ClassLibrary2 project solved the problem. Thanx.